# How to find Js zip version?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, jszip

I have keno-ui (2021-2.616) client side libraries included in the ASP.NET Core project. One of the file included is `jszip.min.js` and I am trying to find what version of JS zip this is.

[image]

Usually author include the version number in file header but its missing here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/2316#issuecomment-438597525) the latest update was to v 2.6.1, as of v2018.3.1017. There is no update on that so I would guess the version jsZip is still 2.6.1.